# Unable to get the result of request using Curl library . Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

I have two controllers, admin, and student.

In my admin controller

```
$url = base_url() . 'index.php/student/list_dashboard_students';
    $student = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($url));
    echo $url;
    print_r($student);
```

In my student controller

```
 <?php

 if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
 exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Student extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
   // $this->admin_model->isLogin();            //$this->admin_model->isStudentAccess($this->session->userdata('role'));
}

function index() {
    $this->list_students();
}
/**
 * return all Student data
 * @access public
 */

function list_students($sort_by = "", $sort_order = "") {
    $_request = $this->input->post();
    //                var_dump($_request);
    //                die;
    $url = base_url()  . "branch/list_branches";
    //                echo $url;
 }
 function list_dashboard_students(){
     $std["list"] = ['ari'];
     //print_r($std);
    return $std;
 }
  ?>
```

But the `print_r` in admin controller `returns blank`. Why is this happening?

Please help me.

Comment: Have you loaded the curl library in admin controller?

Comment: I have used it in autoload.php `$autoload['libraries'] = array("response_messages","validation","Session","Message_stack","curl");`

Answer (score 0):

You should [`curl` Library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl) in Admin Controller.

**In my admin controller**

```
$this->load->library('curl');//load curl library
$url = base_url() . 'index.php/student/list_dashboard_students';
$student = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($url));
echo $url;
print_r($student);
```

**In my student controller**

```
function list_dashboard_students(){
     $std["list"] = ['ari'];
     //print_r($std);
    return json_encode($std);//retrun json encoded data
 }
```

Comment: I have used it in autoload.php  `$autoload['libraries'] = array("response_messages","validation","Session","Message_stack","curl");`